# Chart JS flicker when new data is added to chart (Vue)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I have a Nuxt JS project utilising Chart JS and the Vue Chart JS wrapper. My chart is on the page and visible to the user and new data is added to the chart each time, but old data is never removed *(that's `labels` and `data` for context)*

When I update my chart, I initially call the `update()` method, but also do some cloning to get the chart to update correctly.

However, for some reason, each time the chart updates, lines on the chart as part of my datasets seem to flicker and quickly move down and back up again when new data is added and I don't know why, am I missing an option?

The `<canvas>` element that is in the page never gets removed, just updated with new data.

Since I can't attach a video here, I'll attach my Chart JS plugin with configuration and a scerenshot for context.

```js
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
import _ from 'lodash';
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data () {
    return {
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              color: '#eceaea'
            },
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
              maxTicksLimit: window.innerWidth < 575 ? 2.1 : 4.1,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0
            }
          }]
        },
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0,
            hitRadius: 35
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderLineChart()
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Get chart options
    */
    getChartOptions () {
      return this.options
    },

    /*
    ** Render a line chart
    */
    renderLineChart () {
      const options = this.getChartOptions()

      // this.chartdata is created in the mixin.
      // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
      this.renderChart(this.localData, options)
    }

  },
  computed: {
    localData: function() {
      return this.chartData
    }
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        const options = this.getChartOptions()
        const clone = _.cloneDeep(this.localData)
        this._data._chart.update()
        this.renderChart(clone, options)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

And how my chart looks:

[image: chart]

#### UPDATE

Here's a link to the animation and behaviour I'm talking about: https://www.loom.com/share/a0049ed4a6c54367a82f18452b147903

Comment: For video, you can paste a quick and simple loom link: https://www.loom.com/ Did you inspected your devtools to see if not too much events were sent (could explain the flicker)?

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.loom.com/share/a0049ed4a6c54367a82f18452b147903

Comment: Looks like the data get's empty or reset to 0 and got it's value back again. Did you checked the content of your data with a watcher and a `console.log`?

Comment: The data is never emptied, I'm using a `push()` in my page to push new data into my chart. If I add a `console.log` into my computed property I get the error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` basically means that your code is doing an infinite loop. Not sure what you're currently doing but you should probably debug this and see how you could update the data without an infinite loop. Where is your code for this?

Comment: So not to bloat this Stackoverflow question, the code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099445/chart-js-isnt-dynamically-updating-with-new-data-with-update-method/68099892#68099892 (a related problem to this one)

Comment: Not sure when it does infinite loop, maybe your `mounted()` get's called several times because you somehow `:key` re-render it. Not even sure why you would need to do that on first place. Your chart should react accordingly to your data changes tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to call the update method and the renderChart method of the vue wrapper, this makes the chart first try and update and thus will start animating but then you call render so it will render from scratch, try to only call the update method because if you give new values to chart.js and call the update it handles it internally to render the chart again.

Comment: I'll give this a go and update with my findings!

Comment: If I comment out my `this.renderChart()` inside of my `chartData` watcher and just have my update method, I appear to get an infinite loop and get the error: "You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "chartData" and the chart becomes very laggy

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
this.myChart.destroy()
this.drawchart()
```

as a workaround in the past. (instead of this.myChart.update() )

destroy() come form the library itself and drawchart() was my own written function.

Part of my chart function, btw. i didn't used any vue implemtation, i used the chart.js barebone, maybe your problem is the package itselfe?

```
drawchart() {
                this.ctx = this.$refs['myCanvas'].getContext("2d");
                Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = "rgba(0, 1, 0, 0.1)"
                this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                  
                            labels: this.modelarr,
                            datasets: [{
                                data: this.placeholderData[this.picked]
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            showTooltips: false,
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        min: 0
                                    }
                                }]
                            },                         
                            responsive: true
                        }
                    }),
             
            },

    }
```

Comment: Could you share your `drawchart` function?

Comment: By using `destory` instead of `update` I see no change